# how to concatenate file line sentence in one string in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

hi i am learning python please help me
I am reading a file, line-by-line and i want output for line of words in one String:

for Example 
input file name file.txt and content have file below mentation

Y

X   Y

K   Y

L   Y

expected output

Y

XY

KY

LY

Comment: `''.join(line.split())`

Comment: please write full codes

Answer (score 3):

You can do so with following code:

```
with open('file.txt') as input_file:
    for line in input_file:
        print ''.join(line.split())
```

[`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) will create a list of words by breaking the line at every space and [`join`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) will merge items in a list in to a string.